# How RSA-OAEP decrypt a Symmetric Key message?

Tags: hash, rsa, padding, decryption, oaep

In an RSA-OAEP encrypted symmetric Key (AES for example) message. The message is then decrypted by the other party when R is a Random Number That other party doesn't know about. so How it can retrieve back the key when it's XORed with A Hash (hash1) That it doesn't know. I don't think that output of `Hash2` helps with anything. Right?
[image: RSA_OAEP Padded Message]

Comment: Just reverse the arrows except the hashes.

Comment: well to reach message we will still have to xor with output of hash function ( which is not Known ), what I am asking How message is decrypted back in the real world when R is not known (not sent with message ), or does it get sent with encrypted message in some way Like the IV for symmetric encryption .

Comment: So you got the point. R randomize each encryption even you have the same input.

Comment: @kelalaka Yes of course I know The reason we use a random Number , to prevent same messages to have Same plaintext. I am asking if we hash(R) Then XOr it with Key and send result how we can get key Back if ```R``` is NOT Known so we cant compute hash(R) and cant Xor it with Ciphertext to get key back.

Comment: You have the **input** of Hash2 right? It's in the OAEP padding (P) on the right. So you *can* perform the XOR on the left, and get R back.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes  ohhh, Got it now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAEP is [Optimal asymmetric encryption padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) for RSA and developed by M. Bellare, P. Rogaway, in 1995 and standardized in [PKCS#1 v2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160410165357/http://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf) and [RFC 2437](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2437).

- [Optimal Asymmetric Encryption -- How to encrypt with RSA. Extended abstract in Advances in Cryptology](http://eprint.iacr.org/2000/061.pdf)

Your image hiding some internals of the OAEP. Here a better one;

[image]

The MFG is [Mask Generation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_generation_function) is expected to be a random oracle. The MFGs are similar to a cryptographic hash function except that while a standard hash function's output is a fixed size, the MGF supports output of a variable-length.

If OAEP is developed after the XOF ([Extendable Output Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3)) then the proof will be much easier.

**Back to your question**

> How it can retrieve back the key when it's XORed with A Hash (hash1) That it doesn't know. I don't think that the output of Hash2 helps with anything. Right?

We can formalize above as;

\begin{align}
T &= lhash \mathbin\| PS \| \texttt{01} \mathbin\| Message\\
maskedDB &= MFG1(seed) \oplus T \\
maskedSeed &= MFG2(maskedDB) \oplus seed\\
\end{align}

In the PKCS#1 standard, the same MFG is used as the random oracles. I've made a distinction by numbering. $MFG1$ is taken the $seed$ as input.

Now, you got a message that is sent to you by RSA-OAEP. You get the $maskedSeed$ and $maskedDB$

The $seed$ can be calculated by

$$seed = maskedSeed \oplus maskedDB$$ and now we know the $seed$.

Now the $T$ can be computed by

$$ T = MFG1(seed) \oplus maskedDB $$

Now get the encoded $message$ block and check it.

$$T = lhash \mathbin\| PS \| \texttt{01} \mathbin\| Message$$